# Android Media Player Threading/Concurrency

Tags: java, android, media-player

I am using the default Android Media Player in an Activity, trying to play back a couple of video files. However I have a problem with programming what I want. The desired program outcome would be the following:

- A video file is played back
- After that, a dialog is shown, asking the user something
- A pause of 5 seconds occurs
- The next video is shown
- and so forth

How am I to program this? Currently, I use a paradigm like the following:

- I have a method that sets up the player for the a file, e.g. `playVideo(int)` So I pass it the first file.
- When the player is prepared, it will be started in `onPrepared(MediaPlayer)`.
- When the video is finished, the `onCompletion(MediaPlayer)` listener of the media player shows the dialog to the user by calling `showDialog()`.
- The user accepts the dialog. Before calling `dismiss()` on the dialog, the player object is started for the next file by calling `playVideo(int)`.

This works, but it feels a bit quirky and not clean. And it's of course very procedural. The problems are:

- that I can't figure out how to insert a pause after the dialog is dismissed.
- that I maybe want to change the presentation order of dialogs and videos and this ain't too easy now

Has anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

For the pause, you could use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule an alarm five seconds from now.  It will launch an intent, and that intent could call `playVideo(int)`.

Comment: Thanks, however I am doing everything within one Activity now. A new Intent would mean launching a new Activity, is that right? 

So, summing up: This means I'd have to show only one video per Activity launch, at the `onCompletion` of the video show the dialog, and at the `dismiss()` of the dialog launch a new (delayed) Intent. Is that what you thought of?